# Database Design/Open Form CLICK EVENT in VBA using Access: Specific Inquiry

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access, openform

I wish to program a click event in a "Main Information" form that will open up to 17 other forms based on values selected in a multiple-answer look-up field combo control (corresponding to a numeric ID field/text string categories related via an independent, separate table) housed within that "Main Information" form.

I have learned this is the general code:

```
 Private Sub DiagCat_AfterUpdate()
   Select Case DiagCat
     Case "Cancer [140-208]"
       DoCmd.OpenForm (Cancer_Form)
     Case "Heart Disease [393-398, 402, 410-429]"
       DoCmd.OpenForm (Heart_Disease_Form)
     Case "Stroke [430-438]"
      DoCmd.OpenForm (Stroke_Form)
     Case "Diabetes [250]"
      DoCmd.OpenForm (Diabetes_Form)
     Case "Hypertension [401]"
      DoCmd.OpenForm (Hypertension_Form)
    Case "Liver Disease [070, 571-573]"
      DoCmd.OpenForm (Elevated_Cholesterol_Form)
   End Select
 End Sub
```

VBA issues a "Type Mismatch" error 13 now; the error executes on the 'Case "Cancer [140-208]"' line.

Thank you. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would be wise to tell us which line of the code triggers the error.  This could be the culprit: `DoCmd.OpenForm (Cancer_Form)`  What is `Cancer_Form`?  `OpenForm` needs the form name as a string value, so I'll guess *Cancer_Form* is the name of a form and you should use: `DoCmd.OpenForm "Cancer_Form"`  Parentheses not required.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to your code module's Declarations section.  Then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix anything the compiler complains about, and repeat compile/fix until no more compile errors.

Comment: Thank you so much HansUp! I will try this. If there is no underscore in the Form title, should it be "Cancer Form"?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Double-check the form name in the Navigation pane.  However it's displayed there, put the matching text between the quotes here: `DoCmd.OpenForm "<form Name>"`

Comment: Unfortunately, after I add "Option Explicit", and correct all the form names after the DoCmd's, I still receive a type 13 mismatch error on the line 'Case "Cancer [140-208]"'- unsure what I am doing incorrectly. Thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: Hmm.  What does `DiagCat` actually contain?  What does this tell you? ... `MsgBox "DiagCat value: " & DiagCat & ", DiagCat Type: " & TypeName(DiagCat)`

Comment: Was unable to run that code in the "Immediate" window, for some reason. But, the specific combo box "DiagCat" is a SQL row-sourced reference from a separate table, "DxCats", that uses its "DxCat" text-string field to populate the combo box with:
Cancer [140-208]
Heart Disease [393-398, 402, 410-429]
Stroke [430-438]
Diabetes [250]
Hypertension [401]
Elevated Cholesterol [272]
Liver Disease [070, 571-573], etc.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Add that `MsgBox` statement in a new line in your VBA code just before the `Select Case DiagCat` line.   Then run the code.

Comment: I figured out how to run your code as a macro; strangely, it lists the data type as "empty"- I have no idea why.

Comment: If you can share a copy of your db, I'll see if I can figure out why it gives you empty instead of one of the expected string values.

Comment: No it gives me the same Type 13 mismatch error on your added line of code beginning with "MsgBox". If this is taking up too much of your time no worries; thanks for all your efforts thus far.

Comment: The time issue is secondary just now.  I just don't see how to help without examining your db details.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Select Case` keyword is what you need to select an action based on multiple values of a field.

```
Private Sub cmdOpen_Click() 'where cmdOpen is the button control clicked to open the forms
      Select Case cmbDxCatsID 'assuming cmbDxCatsID is the name of the combobox control on the form
      Case 1
          DoCmd.OpenForm(Form1)
      Case 2
          DoCmd.OpenForm(Form2)
      'etc.........
      End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very grateful!

Comment: Woops- new to StackOverflow- I clicked the check- I think that accepts it. Thanks again!

Comment: So unfortunately, even though I think this is the right way to go about this, I am still getting errors. The specific combo box that is used to generate the "select case" DoCmds is actually a drop-down box that uses SQL to generate LookUp values from another independent table. I was trying to have the cases be specific text strings of the categories able to be chosen, but Access/VBA keeps telling me there is a "Type Mismatch"; is there anyway to referenced the table/field/values of the table each look-up value refers to? Am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: I also tried moving the "click event" from an independent button to the very drop down combo box control itself, to Open Forms on the After Update event: